# grabToImage with Char View in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qimage, qchartview

I'm having a problem. I hope everyone will help me! My English is not good, hope everyone is sorry.

I have a chart view and a horizontal scroll bar. When the horizontal scroll bar changes in the x axis, the points in the next array are drawn on the chart view. I have a chart view and a horizontal scroll bar. When the horizontal scroll bar changes in the x axis, the points in the next array are drawn on the chart view. I would like to capture (grabtoImage) all the chart views including those that are not displayed on the screen, it only shows when changing the scroll bar, into multiple image.*  Ex: A screen draws 60 point (timer 60s). When timer is 180s will have 3 image is captured.

[image]

I hope people can suggest me solutions to solve my problem. Thank you so much everyone!

---

> My source code: 
>   Rectangle draw on chart view:

```
Rectangle{
    id: recZoom
    width: 3 
    height: parent.height   

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseLeft
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: Qt.SizeHorCursor
        drag.target: parent
        drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
        onMouseXChanged{
            if(drag.active) {
                if(DisplayMain.ValueAxisX.min > 0){
                    // draw point to chart view
                    // cal position min max of scroll bar
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> Create ShaderEffectSource get data from zoom rectangle

```
ShaderEffectSource{
    id: shaderZoom
    width: recZoom.width
    height: recZoom.height
    live: false
    opacity: 0
    smooth: true
}
```

> grabtoImage shaderzoom

```
if(extendFile === "pdf"){
shaderZoom.live = true;
shaderZoom.scheduleUpdate();
shaderZoom.grabToImage(function(result) {
                       result.saveToFile("something.png");
                   });
```

}

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I have not solution to solve this problem :(. So, I hope to find a good solution from you.

Comment: you say you have a code that prints partially print what you want, then it will be easy to show it.

Comment: oh, thanks you. I will show my source.